# NxLogs to Fluentd/SSL?

Tags: ssl, fluent, fluentd, nxlog

I have a bunch of linux servers configured to push logs to another fluentd server using the fluent-secure-output plugin. Now I'd like to configure our windows servers using nxlogs.

I read a bit on the om_ssl nxlogs module, but I am puzzled about the shared key. Basically, fluentd's secure-output plugin requires a shared key to be identical everywhere for authentication (this is not tied to the certificates at all). But I can't see how I could specify this key in nxlog's om_ssl configuration.

Is this even supported at all? Is it possible to use nxlogs to forward to an ssl fluentd server?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they have their own authentication protocol over TLS that uses shared_keys (i.e. passphrase) on the client side instead of using private keys. I don't know why that is needed but NXLog and most other log aggregator solutions (rsyslog, syslog-ng, logstash, etc) use plain TLS which can provide proper authentication for both the client and the server.

The protocol is described in their [GitHub README](https://github.com/mururu/fluent-plugin-secure-forward/blob/master/README.md) and I doubt it will work with NXLog's om_ssl or anything else other than Fluentd's out_secure_forward.

Answer (score 0):

The Fluentd input/output plugin to forward fluentd messages over SSL with authentication, works only between the two plugin (which is actually the [same one](https://github.com/tagomoris/fluent-plugin-secure-forward)) using authentication by shared_key check from both of client(out_secure_forward) and server(in_secure_forward).

So unfortunately you can't sent it through your nxlog only through [out_secure_forward](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/out_secure_forward).